# How to add an "External" CodeDom provider for xsd.exe?

Tags: .net, f#, nuget, xsd.exe

I am generating F# classes from XSD [using an example](https://mdavey.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/f-and-xsd-exe/). How can `xsd.exe` find and use `FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom`, which is a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom/)?

```
xsd.exe fpml-asset-4-2.xsd /classes
  /l:”Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider,
  FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=1.9.9.9, Culture=neutral,
  PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809″</code>
```

Yields an error: `there is no codedom provider defined for the package`.

Which is expected, because I am executing "global" `xsd.exe` without knowledge of this package. Obviously, `gacutil` does not find `FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider` in the dotnet assembly:

```
> gacutil -l | find "FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom"
>
```

How can I execute `xsd.exe` so it is aware of this [codedom provider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom/)? Bonus points for not messing up the state of my .NET installation.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to get this work (AFAIK, `xsd.exe` is pretty much hard coded to support VB and C# only). The best option is to generate C# code, compile it and use that from F#. Even better would be contributing to the XSD type provider in F# Data :-) https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/tree/XsdProvider

Comment: Link in the previous comment is dead. Looks like the documentation has been moved to https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html